# poetry add using a caret and a @ symbol

Tags: python, python-poetry

I am confused as to what the "@" operator actually does in `poetry add pandas@^1.3.0`.

Both following commands install pandas version **1.5.3** and set the dependency in my pyproject.toml to `pandas = "^1.3.0"`:

```
poetry add pandas@^1.3.0
poetry add pandas^1.3.0
```

I have no other dependencies listed (aside from Python 3.8).

I thought that using the "@" symbol signifies a *strict* requirement for a specific version and its compatible releases. With "pandas@^1.3.0," shouldn't Poetry install exactly the version 1.3.0 of the "pandas" package?

The [official documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#using-the--operator) says:

> When adding dependencies via poetry add, you can use the @ operator.
> This is understood similarly to the == syntax, but also allows
> prefixing any specifiers that are valid in pyproject.toml. For
> example:

Comment: There are actually 2 transitions here: first: `poetry add ---> *.toml` then the actual fetch of the packages. I think that this gap is the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "@" operator in the add command is **a delimiter** between the package name and the version.

If the "@" operator is followed by its required version, e.g.

```
poetry add pendulum@2.0.5
```

is the same as:

```
poetry add pendulum==2.0.5
```

If you use caret, e.g.:

```
poetry add requests@^2.13.0
```

Then you specify [a version range](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#caret-requirements).

The "@" symbol signifies a strict requirement **only if you don't use any other** specifier afterwards. The poetry [documentation for "@" operator](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#using-the--operator) is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If the intention is to pin the package to a specific version, then  "==" is what we must be using, and it clearly outlined in : [https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#exact-requirements](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#exact-requirements.)

Coming to your question, what you have attempted are the below:

poetry add pandas@^1.3.0

poetry add pandas^1.3.0

The caret(^) symbol allows upgrades to a later version as long as it doesn't modify the left most non-zero(major version) digit. So even though you say ^1.3.0, it finds the latest version of pandas with major version 1 (https://pypi.org/project/pandas/#history), which is 1.5.3.

If you are keen on using @ ,please do give a try with "poetry add pandas@1.3.0".

Comment: @mousetailEdited answer.

Answer (score 0):

> With "pandas@^1.3.0," shouldn't Poetry install exactly the version 1.3.0 of the "pandas" package?

No. According to the docs it requires that the *minimal* version is `1.3.0`
and the maximal is strictly less than `2.0.0`. [Reference](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#add):

```
# Allow >=2.0.5, <3.0.0 versions
poetry add pendulum@^2.0.5
```